# DataGrip: Returned values are inline

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'm not sure how this happened, but now each new query has a faint gray line above it and the returned results display inline rather below in the console. I'm not sure what this is called in order to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That calls 'In-editor results' and can be deactivated by this button
[image: in-edit results]
or in File | Settings | Database | General -> 'Show output results in editor'.